# Scroll animation doesn't work on IE and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element that fills the screen, under that is another element but this one is hidden so you can't scroll to it manually.

My CSS stylesheet looks like this for that:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#page1, #content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#content {
    top: 100%;
    display:none;
}
```

`#page1` stands for the element that fills the screen and `#content` stands for the element which is underneath that.

When I click on a button on the first element (which fills the screen), it shows the element under that and smoothly scrolls down to that.

I was using this piece of code in the first place:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#exploreBtn').on('click', function() {
        $('#content').fadeIn(500);
        console.log($("#content").offset().top)
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
        }, 1000, function(){
            $("#page1").css('display','none');
            $('#content').css('top',0);
            $(document).scrollTop(0);
        });
    });
});
```

Which works in IE and Mozilla, but I've tried to improve it...

Now I'm using this code:

```
$(function() {
    var headerLoaded = true,
            contentLoaded = false,
            header = "#fitScreen",
            exploreBtn = "#exploreBtn",
            scrollBackBtn = "#scrollBackBtn",
            content = "#content";



    $(exploreBtn).on('click', function() {
        if (!contentLoaded && headerLoaded) {
            showScrollHide(content, header, function() {zit
                var sum = ($('nav').height()) + parseInt($('nav').css('margin-bottom'));
                $('#panelContent').css('margin-top', sum);
                
               
                $('#content').css('top', 0);
                $('html, body').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
                
                $(window).scrollTop(0);

                headerLoaded = false;
                contentLoaded = true;
            });
        }
    });

    var showScrollHide = function(element, hide, func) {
        $(element).fadeIn(500, function() {
            $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(element).offset().top
            }, 1000, function() {
                $(hide).fadeOut(100, func);
            });
        });
    };

});
```

And for some reason, it doesn't work on IE and Mozilla.

It just gives me a slight delay, and then it fades in the screen I'm scrolling to.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Worked for me with IE11. Can you please explain what you mean when you say "doesn't work"?

Comment: Also worked for me on Firefox 29.0.1...

Comment: Oh, the fiddle is working, but you're talking about your own code... can you post that code on a new fiddle and tell us what's not working?

Comment: Nvm, got it already, i was using only `$('body').animate({` and it should be `$('html, body').animate({`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your new code, you have this part :

```
$(element).fadeIn(500, function() {
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top
    }, 1000, function() {
        $(hide).fadeOut(100, func);
    });
});
```

The difference between your working code and your not working code is which element you animate the scroll.

In you working code, you are animating `'body, html'`. Depending on browser, the scrollbar is not on the same element. Hence, that's why you should target both html and body element :

```
$(element).fadeIn(500, function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ //HERE!
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top
    }, 1000, function() {
        $(hide).fadeOut(100, func);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah man, just figured that :D accepting the answer as soon as i could.